# PHP missing environment variables

Tags: php, environment-variables

I am attempting to set some global environment variables in `/etc/environment`, which should be available to PHP.  But I cannot figure out how to get PHP to recognize the variables when running via **php-fpm**, but it does when running via **php-cli**.

**/etc/php-fpm.conf:**

```
clear_env = no
```

**/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:**

```
clear_env = no
```

**/etc/environment:**

```
FOO=42
```

The FOO variable is available in my shell:

```
echo $FOO                             # prints 42
```

The FOO variable is available to PHP when running in CLI:

```
echo getenv('FOO') . "\n";            // prints 42
```

But FOO variable is not available to PHP when running through FPM:

```
echo getenv("FOO") . "\n";            // prints nothing
echo $_ENV["FOO"] . "\n";             // prints nothing
echo $_SERVER["FOO"] . "\n";          // prints nothing
```

How do I get **php-fpm** to not clear the environment?

Comment: ...Did you restart php-fpm after?

Comment: Yes.  I have attempted to find somewhere I can verify the `clear_env` setting is being picked up (like using `phpinfo()`), but I have had no luck.

Comment: serverfault.com may be a better place to ask. There's a php-fpm tag there, but not here.

Comment: @Barmar depending on what exactly the solution is, it actually may be on-topic on either site.

Comment: @bwoebi Isn't that backwards? The proper place to ask depends on what the answer is? But if you don't know the answer, how do you know where to ask?

Comment: @Barmar well, that's the paradox.

Answer (score 2):

After lots more experience with systemd, I have discovered a workaround solution.

Open the option file for the php7.2-fpm service

```
systemctl edit php7.2-fpm
```

Add the following

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

Restart the service

```
systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```